# How to install PostGIS correctly with OpenGeo Suite 4.0 community edition on Windows 7?

Tags: postgis, windows, boundless-suite

I have installed the OpenGeo Suite community edition, version 3, onto Windows 7 multiple times in the past, with virtually no problems. 
With the latest version of OpenGeo Suite (4.0.1) (which includes PostGIS 2.1), I am able to install almost all of the components successfully, except PostGIS. With earlier editions, PostGIS was installed as part of the full Opengeo installation process, but now, although PostGreSQL 9.3 is successfully installed, there are no PostGIS or opengeo database templates installed, nor are the spatial functions installed. Nevertheless PostGIS 2.1 is installed.

It seems that OpenGeo Suite 4 intalls all the component but no longer creates a default database or user account in Postgresql/PostGIS.

What steps are necessary to configure OpenGeosuite (windows installation) in order to be able to fix this issue?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

What you are running into is that [PostGIS](http://www.postgis.net) has changed the way it is installed.  It is now installed as a simple extension to [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org), in whichever database you choose.  This means that there is no longer a template database created.

Here is the help documentation on [Creating a spatial database using Extensions](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db_extensions).

The new steps to create a spatially enabled database are:

1. Create a new database:  `createdb [yourdatabase]`
2. Install the PostGIS extension:  `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

Further, you now install the Tiger Geocoder using an extension as well:  [Tiger Geocoder Enabling your PostGIS database: Using Extension](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/postgis_installation.html#install_tiger_geocoder_extension)

Here is a screenshot of a PostgreSQL database that I have created, with the PostGIS and geocoding extensions installed.
[image: Postgresql with spatial extension]

To be clear, the [Opengeo Suite 4](http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/opengeo-suite/) contains everything you need to create a spatial database.  You've already installed the correct components.  The configuration step is not with the Opengeo Suite, but as a simple enabling process in PostgreSQL itself.

On that note, it would be useful for the [Boundlessgeo](http://boundlessgeo.com) people to add this particularly pertinent change into their [release notes](http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/opengeo-suite/release-notes/) for the software.

Comment: Glad I could help. As a means of helping others who are searching for a similar problem, please mark this answer as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. I input in psql console: psql -d [yourdatabase] -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;" (my example: psql -d testgis -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"). But nothing happens then...

Comment: Reinstalling everything with 32 bit versions helped ;)